# How do I extract a RPM file?

Tags: extract, rpm

I've RPM file of which I want to examine its file contents. For `.deb` packages, I can use `dpkg -x file.deb` to extract it.

What is the equivalent command for a `.rpm` file? I'm looking for a command-line application.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`file-roller` seems to open *rpm* files. Alternatively you can use the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rpm2cpio
$ rpm2cpio /path/to/file.rpm | cpio -i --make-directories
```

that will extract the *rpm* content to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, I just came across it: `rpm2cpio file.rpm | cpio --extract --make-directories`

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, my MATE app (Engrampa) first failed with "Unrecognized file format", but after installing `rpm2cpio` as suggested as alternative here, also the app now can read the RPM file. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Install 7z:

```
apt install p7zip-full
```

and extract:

```
7z x /path/to/file.rpm 
7z x /path/to/file.cpio -o/path/to/extract/folder/
```

Comment: Unfortunately 7z is not aware of file permissions and for rpm packages which contain executables (i.e. most of them) this can be a problem.

Comment: @Wug to overcome the limitations of `7z`: after the first step you can extract the `file.cpio` using `(cd /path/to/extract/folder/ ; cpio -i -d </path/to/file.cpio)`.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember you have to use a app called alien which transforms .rpm to deb files. Use a terminal to do :

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

then

```
sudo alien -d nameofyourpackage.rpm (-d for Debian package)
```

If you then need to examine it you can resort to your dpkg -x file.deb method

Comment: `rpm2cpio` seems to work fine, so I haven't tried this one.

Comment: this has the drawback of creating a .deb first.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use alien to only extract the files (which it calls "generate a build tree")

`alien --scripts --generate <package.rpm>`

You will get 2 dirs - `<package>`, and `<package>.orig`, which is the raw extraction from the rpm.